# How to use message data outside the message event?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

```
  client.on('message ',function(message){
       console.log(message)
    });
```

In the above asynchronous code how do i use the message data outside the message event??

Comment: Use event emitters in node JS for above functionality

Answer (score 0):

In general, you don't use it outside that callback.  You put whatever code wants to use the message in that callback or in a function that you call from that callback.

Because `client.on('message', ...)` is event driven, you don't know when it's going to happen.  So, if you store the data somewhere else and expect some future code to use it, there's no way for the rest of your code to know the data is now there and valid.

So, whatever code wants that message needs to be put inside this callback or inside a function you call from this callback.  The usual model is that you process the data live in this callback when it arrives or you call some function to "push" the data to some other function so it can process the data.

There are certain (generally rare) circumstances where you collect the data and some future event will then process the data, but I'm guessing that's not what you're doing here.  If it is, then you would just add this data to some collection that is part of some higher scope.

If you gave us more specifics on your real-world problem, we could be a lot more specific with suggestions for how to solve that particular problem.  As your question is written now it's a generic question with no specific details so all we can do is offer a generic answer with no specific suggestions or details.

Since it looks like you're new here, new people here often tend to think they should write their question in a generic fashion with code they made up (pseudo code).  That's usually a bad choice.  If you show us your real problem and your real code, we can offer you in-depth specific solutions and code for your exact problem and we can offer you solutions or suggestions you didn't even know to ask about.  You will get better answers if you show your real code with your real problem, not a generic version you made up just for stackoverflow.